# Javascript: reducing down to one number

Tags: javascript, arrays, modulo

So I need to take a date and convert it into one single number by adding up each digit, and when the sum exceeds 10, I need to add up the two digits.  For the code below, I have 12/5/2000, which is 12+5+2000 = 2017.  So 2+0+1+7 = 10 & 1+0 = 1.  I get it down to one number and it works in Firebug (output of 1).  However, it is not working in a coding test environment I am trying to use, so I suspect something is wrong.  I know the code below is sloppy, so any ideas or help reformatting the code would be helpful!  (Note:  I am thinking it has to be a function embedded in a function, but haven't been able to get it to work yet.)

```
var array = [];
var total = 0;

    function solution(date) {
      var arrayDate = new Date(date);
      var d = arrayDate.getDate();
      var m = arrayDate.getMonth();
      var y = arrayDate.getFullYear();
      array.push(d,m+1,y);

        for(var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          total += array[i];
        };
          if(total%9 == 0) {
            return 9;
          } else
            return total%9;    
    };

solution("2000, December 5");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a recursive function call

```js
function numReduce(numArr){
   //Just outputting to div for demostration
   document.getElementById("log").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend","Reducing: "+numArr.join(","));
   
   //Using the array's reduce method to add up each number
   var total = numArr.reduce(function(a,b){return (+a)+(+b);});

   //Just outputting to div for demostration
   document.getElementById("log").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",": Total: "+total+"<br>");
   
   if(total >= 10){
      //Recursive call to numReduce if needed, 
      //convert the number to a string and then split so 
      //we will have an array of numbers
      return numReduce((""+total).split(""));
   }
   return total;
}
function reduceDate(dateStr){
   var arrayDate = new Date(dateStr);
   var d = arrayDate.getDate();
   var m = arrayDate.getMonth();
   var y = arrayDate.getFullYear();
   return numReduce([d,m+1,y]);
}
alert( reduceDate("2000, December 5") );
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is your final code your function is not outputting anything. Try this:

```
var array = [];
var total = 0;

    function solution(date) {
      var arrayDate = new Date(date);
      var d = arrayDate.getDate();
      var m = arrayDate.getMonth();
      var y = arrayDate.getFullYear();
      array.push(d,m+1,y);

        for(var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          total += array[i];
        };
          if(total%9 == 0) {
            return 9;
          } else
            return total%9;    
    };

alert(solution("2000, December 5"));
```

It will alert the result in a dialog.